# Ansible grep from shell variable

Tags: variables, grep, ansible, mtu

I am trying to create an Ansible playbook to pull out MTU size for exact NIC (unfortunately i have 5k VMs and this exact NIC does not have the same name on all VMs). I need to parse IP from file to variable and grep by that.

My command i will use in playbook:

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a | grep -C 1 $IP | grep MTU | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c 5-10
```

And output should be looking like this:

```
9000
```

Comment: What did you try and what is your exact problem ?

Comment: I am starting with Ansible and i don't have any idea how to deal with it.
I wan't to have in file IP addresses and grep ifconfig output with this IP.

Answer (score 0):

This one `gnu awk` command should do:

```
ifconfig -a | awk -v ip="$IP" -v RS= -F'MTU:' '$0~ip {split($2,a," ");print a[1]}'
9216
```

Another variations

```
ifconfig -a | awk -v ip="$IP" 'f {split($6,a,":");print a[2];exit} $0~ip{f=1}'
ifconfig -a | awk -v ip="$IP" 'f {print substr($6,5,99);exit} $0~ip{f=1}'
9216
```

Comment: I need to read a file in a loop and set each IP under $IP variable and use it in ansible playbook.